# Make request to Flask view from Flask-Script command

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask view that returns some JSON data and want to get that same data in a Flask-Script command. I was going to use the Requests library but don't know what URL to use without hard-coding the host. How can I get the JSON data returned by the view?

```
@manager.command
def showdata():
    data = requests.get('/data-page')  # fails, needs full URL
    print(data.json())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in your code, you don't need to make an external request. Use the `test_client` to make a request.

```
c = app.test_client()
r = c.get('/data-page')
data = json.loads(r.get_data(as_text=True))
print(data)
```

Ideally, extract the logic from the presentation in the view and just call a function rather than making any request at all.

```
# command
print(get_data())

# view
return jsonify(get_data())
```